LoopTool is overlapping edges
I dont know why but every time i try to make a circle using loop tool inside a mesh, the edges overlap thenselfs in that weird way. Could it be due to the number of faces I'm trying to convert using the LoolTool? or some wrong configuration?




Looptools work on the outer edge, the rest is unchanged.
There is simply no space for the circle to form without going out of the limits.
You can try to do the same for the next inner edge.
